# Auto insert data to a mysql table column according to another Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 4 mysql tables, Table_1, Table_2, Table_3, Table_4
Table_1, Includes 6 columns named(item2_ID,item2_name,Item3_ID,item3_name,item4_ID,item4_ID) and tables Table_2,Table_3,Table_4 each have two columns named(item2_ID,item2_name),(item3_ID,item3_name),(item4_ID,item4_name) in which assign each unique item_ID to an item_name.

By php & html form, I only receive the items IDs to insert into Table_1 ID columns.
Now I want Item_names to be inserted automatically to 'Item_name'columns of Table_1 according to 3 other tables. So, for example, a row in Table_1 will include all item_IDs(received by html form) and all item_names(inserted in the same row using other 3 tables). How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you want an insert trigger.  But it is a bit hard to follow your question with no sample data and concrete explanation of what you really want done.

Comment: if you only know the item_id to insert, then you can do ```insert into table_1 (item_id, item_name) (select t2.item_id, t2.item_name from table2 t2 where t2.item_id=$item_id);``` not elegant, but still a one liner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you assigned the value of item id from your form to a php variable `$itemID`. Your query will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table_1 (item_id, item_name) SELECT t2.item_id, t2.item_name FROM Table_2 t2 WHERE t2.item_id = $itemID
```

Please note that you do not need the keyword `VALUES` when you are inserting from a select statement.

I'll keep the above in case you need to refer back to it. As for the new question, I would do that in PHP and not as a query.

Simply select the values from 3 tables into an array and then build an insert query:

Let's say you have an array (let's call it `$myvalues`) that you got from your select statements:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => Name2
    [2] => 2
    [3] => Name3
    [4] => 3
    [5] => Name4
)
```

For simplicity sake this is your query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Table_2 VALUES ('" . implode("','", $myvalues) . "')";
```

Which will give you:

```
INSERT INTO Table_2 VALUES ('1','Name2','2','Name3','3','Name4');
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, just use the above query and change the table_2 to whatever tables you may have...

Comment: Then, How should I modify the WHERE statement since I'm inserting from multiple tables? What will the WHERE statement be for something like this: INSERT INTO Table_1 (item1_name, item2_name, item3_name, item4_name) SELECT t2.item1_name, t3.item2_name,t4.item3_name FROM Table_2 t2, Table_3 t3, Table_4 t4 WHERE... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do separate queries for each table.

Comment: I've already tried this way. The problem is, each of the item_names(item1_name,item2_name,...)will be inserted into a new row, rather than all being inserted into one row.

Comment: You have 2 columns in table_1. How do you want 6 values in 2 columns? Comma separated? Edit your question and a second part with detail of how your table_1 rows should look. I'll then edit my response.

Comment: Edited my question. I appreciate your editing your response. Thanks.